# window.close() not working on pop up with pop up

Tags: javascript, popup, window.closed

I have a Customer Info form that has anchor tag "close" that should close the current window. This customer form is being opened as pop up. The Customer form also has a search btn that when clicked it pop ups the search form that is being run by a javascript called searchOrder.js. So basically it is a pop up inside a pop up. The customer form's close btn is not working but when the reference to searchOrder.js is removed, it begins to work. Also, when the search pop up is open and I click the "close" anchor tag, it closes the search pop up but never the current window which is the customer form.
Ive tried a lot of solutions already but nothing is working. I used self.close(), window.opener.close(), made it a btn instead of a link etc.,c alled a function onclick

```
    function closeWindow() {

        var closeRef;

 window.opener='x';                             
            closeRef =  window.open('','_parent','');
//or closeRef = window.open("",name);
            closeRef.close();

           }
```

heres my gsp code:

```
    <g:form  method="post" name="CustomerInfoForm" target="_parent" role="form">
    <div class="id="closeLink"><a href="JavaScript:window.close()">Close</a></div>
    <button id="searchOrderButton" type="button" class="button" onclick="searchOrder(document.forms[0].summaryMessage.value,'summaryMessageText','${createLink(action:'searchOrder')}','${createLinkTo(dir:'images',file:'closeButton.gif')}')" value="Search Order">Check Order</button>   
   </g:form>
```

How do I make the current window (customer info ) close? tnx

Comment: Why do you need a function for this? `window.close()` should do what you need.

Comment: The close() method closes only windows opened by JavaScript using the open method. If you attempt to close any other window, a confirm message is displayed, asking the user to choose whether the window is to be closed or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten `window.close()` to just `close()` and shorten `window.open()` to `open()`. Maybe you'll find what you need here, though:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_win_closed

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp

Comment: tnx but my form has a diff case. i used that in the first place and was not working that's why i posted here. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a function like this to close your popup window :

```
<g:form  method="post" name="CustomerInfoForm" target="_parent" role="form">
    <div class="id="closeLink">
         <a href="JavaScript:closepopup()">Close</a>
    </div>
    <button id="searchOrderButton" type="button" class="button" onclick="searchOrder(document.forms[0].summaryMessage.value,'summaryMessageText','${createLink(action:'searchOrder')}','${createLinkTo(dir:'images',file:'closeButton.gif')}')" value="Search Order">Check Order</button>   
</g:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function openpopup()
   {
      my_window = window.open("","myPopup","status=1,width=100,height=100");
   }

   function closepopup()
   {
      if(false == my_window.closed)
      {
         my_window.close ();
      }
   }
</script>
```

EDIT : Don't forget to open your popup with the openpopup() function :

```
<a href="javascript: openpopup()">Open Popup Window</a>
```

Comment: I wanted to try this but I am not sure how because the trigger to the Customer info pop up is from a btn that belongs to a diff project. A totally different technology while the Customer info pop up is displayed in a frame in grails. :(

Comment: Have you tried `<a href="javascript:self.close('window_name');">Close</a>` ? Not sure if it works in your case but it's still worth giving it a try !

Comment: im not sure this is possible, the window name is not stored in the pop up html itself. is there a way I can get the window name with out using the var popName=window.open()? tnx

Comment: yes, there are ways to do so, but you need to give more details about the different project that initially opens the popup. You really have no idea how it is opened ? Javascript, Asp.net or whatever ?

Comment: i have an idea. this is the code that opens it attached to click command of the btn. in java. gwt. custom class. OurWindow.open(createCustomerURL, "process", "height=600,width=800,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no", true);